# mysql search for duplicates by column A and delete by criteria on othe columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates, criteria

I have a mysql database, containing a table with following columns: PartCode, Price and Quantity. The goal is to write a query which would search for rows with duplicate 'PartCode', then compare them by Price and Quantity, and delete the row with higher 'Price' values, but if one of the 'Quantities' is 0, then to delete the one with 0 quantity.

```
A sample table would look like this:  
PartCode  -  Price  -  Quantity
 ABCD     -    5    -     2
 CDEF     -    6    -     1
 CDEF     -    4    -     1
 VZXY     -    8    -     4
 VZXY     -    7    -     0
 ....     -   ...   -    ...

And for the results, I'd like to get this:
PartCode  -  Price  -  Quantity
 ABCD     -    5    -     2
 CDEF     -    4    -     1
 VZXY     -    8    -     4
 ....     -   ...   -    ...
```

I've found the solution to receive all duplicate PartCodes:

```
SELECT `PartCode` FROM `Table` GROUP BY `PartCode` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

What I cannot figure out, is how to implement it to delete one of the duplicates, by other columns comparison.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will delete one record from each `PartCode` group having either the highest quantity, or if one record has a zero quantity then it would be deleted instead.

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE (PartCode, Quantity) IN
(
    SELECT
        t.PartCode,
        t.qty
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            PartCode,
            CASE WHEN MIN(Quantity) = 0 THEN MIN(Quantity) ELSE MAX(Quantity) END AS qty
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY PartCode
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t
)
```

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply, but as I am a beginner, I have some follow-ups. For one, I get an error at the first 't1', which I don't fully understand. Secondly, from what I understand, the "CASE WHEN" part with quantities selects the higher quantity and I should end up with a result of those duplicate rows mixed into one, whereas I am looking to just remove the row, not matching my criteria (This I did not clarify in my original question). And third, how should the logic change if in the future I will have more than two duplicates? Thanks again!

Comment: @Paulius Tough query, my first approach was wrong, please try my update.

Comment: So after few attempts, I removed the "t1" and figured out, that SQL gives an error because I want to delete from same "yourTable" which is called upon later in line 8. When I changed "yourTable" in line 2, to another table and only referenced to "yourTable" in line 8, it passed. Is there any way to work around this? Or should I create a duplicate table, just to perform this query? The error i got is this: "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'MergedData' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Now it's working quite good. From here on I believe I will be capable to adjust to filter also by 'Price', but the interesting thing, is that in my sample table, I've had 50 duplicating PartCodes, but your script removes 51 entry and still leaves one PartCode duplicate. I checked, and that remaining duplicate and it's still there because originally there appears to have been three entries with same PartCode. How should the code be modified to accommodate more than two matching entries? Or maybe I should just run the query again, until there is no more duplicates?

Comment: Do you want to always be left with just one entry?  Or, in the case of 3 part duplicate records, do you want to only delete one record, leaving you with 2?

Comment: The goal is to have only one left. In other words result needs to have only unique PartCodes, filtered by quantity and price.

Comment: I think this would be very difficult to do with MySQL, which has no row number functionality, and off the top of my head I don't know how to do this with your current logic.  If you could provide logic for which single record to _retain_ then maybe I can update my answer.

Comment: Here's the good thing: You can just run my DELETE script multiple times until you are left with just one record per `PartCode` group.  Not perfect, but if it lets you proceed to your next task then so be it.